# R: Mclust function error

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I am trying to run the Mclust function (from mclust package) for a small data set (106x2). I am running the 3.2.1 R version for OS X 10.10.3. However, I am getting the following error:

```
Error in if (loglik > signif(.Machine$double.xmax, 6) || any(!c(scale,  : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
Called from: meEVV(data = data, z = z, prior = prior, control = control, warn = warn)
```

The data set has no missing data. Here it is,

```
4.2 5
4.2 6
4   5
4   5
4.2 5
4.4 5
3.9 5
4.2 5
3.9 6
4.4 7
4.9 6
4.1 5
4.1 5
4.9 6.5
3.9 5
4.7 5
5.1 5
5.2 6
4.8 6.5
5.2 5
4.5 5
5.1 5
4.2 5
4.4 5
4.1 5
4.4 5
4.2 5
5.1 5
6.1 5
4.2 5
4   5.5
4.2 5
5   5.5
4.2 5
3.9 5
3.9 5
4   5
4.7 5
3.9 5
5.3 5
4.4 5
4.4 5
4.3 5
4.7 5
4.6 6
4.8 5
4   5
4.3 5
3.6 5
4   5
4.1 5
3.8 5
3.9 5
5.2 5
4.7 5
3.9 5
4.8 5
4.9 5
5.7 6.5
5.4 5
5.4 6
4.3 5
3.8 5
4.8 5
4.8 6
3.9 5.5
3.9 5
5.3 5
5.5 7
4.4 5
3.8 5
4.3 7
4   5
4.9 5
4.4 5
4.8 5
3.7 5
3.9 6
4.7 5
3.8 5
4.5 6
3.9 5
4.8 5
5.1 5
5.3 5
4.5 5
5.3 5
4.5 5
5.1 5
3.7 5
5.4 5
4.2 5
4   5
4.6 5
4.6 5
4.7 5
4.3 6
4.3 5
4.3 6.5
4.1 5
4.5 5
4.4 5
3.7 5
3.8 5
3.5 5
4.4 5
```

Do you know how can I fix it? Thank you.

Comment: `dput` is a good way to provide a sample data set for your question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: it works if you add a tiny bit of noise, `dat + rnorm(nrow(dat)*2, 0, 0.000001)`

Answer (score 0):

Variable 2 had only five levels.

This most likely causes numerical problems, due to the **lack of variance** in some subsets.

Most clustering algorithm really really need *continuous* data. (Steps of 0.5 aren't truly continuous. Scale the second value by 2, and you have integers 10,11,12,13,14 only, that is discrete.)

But I do not think this really is a clustering problem.

Instead, you may be attempting to do *regression* or some other prediction by clustering?

Answer (score 0):

the problem could exist with some of the models that mclust uses but not all of them.
I suggest to try clustering with each model separately and compare the result for the ones that don't lead to this error.

for example just try EII and VII:
   Mclust(datazs[-13], modelNames = c("EII", "VII"))